# How to check which app changes home background image

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen, background-process

The background of my homescreen keeps changing and I do not know what causes it. I can change the background manually, but after a certain moment of time it just changes automatically to another background. It is really annoying. I mean... I do not hate baby's. But I do not want them randomly eating biscuits on the background of my phone .

Comment: Do you use a custom launcher?

Comment: I mean a third-party launcher

Comment: Have set any live wallpaper?

Comment: I am using the default Oneplus launcher, but same kept happening, using the Nova launcher. I do not think I have a live wallpaper (how can I check that?). And isn't the live wallpaper overwritten anyway when I select a new background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app must have the permission [`android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SET_WALLPAPER) to change wallpaper. I suggest you find out which apps have that permission and than try to disable or remove some of those app one by one until you no longer have that problem.

You can use a permission checker app to find those app. User Izzy maintains a nice list [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379) if you need help finding one. I have used [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat) earlier so I'm showing you how you can use it to list all the apps having that permission.

1. Launch the app.
2. Choose List apps by permission
3. Scroll down and choose Misc. Permission
4. Tap the three horizontal line icon next the Misc. Permission to list the permissions instead of the apps.
5. In the search bar (tap the lens icon) type `android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER`
6. Under Set Wallpaper category you can find the apps which have the permission to change wallpaper.